# How to properly remove an object that stick out above horizon using Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, object-removal

I have the picture (file format: **JPEG**):
[image]

I'm using **Photoshop CC (2015.5.1)**. I'm trying to remove the building on the right side of the picture. It sticks up above horizon.

I tried to remove the building with a `Smudge tool` in Photoshop. But I don't think this is right. My result is not good. I don't know how to do it properly so that image is not affected heavily.

---

This is what I get using `Smudge tool`:
[image]

---

How to properly remove unwanted objects that stick out above horizon?

---

**Update:**

As @Tetsujin suggested I used **Spot Healing Brush**. It worked perfectly. In my case it was better than **Smudge tool**. Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spot Healing Brush is good in this kind of situation.
This is the result of a *single* click using it - not perfect in itself, but an easy starting point for any further correction you want to make.

[image]

Make sure the brush surrounds the offending object with sufficient background around it to adequately identify the portion you wish to replace.

*Edit:* Brought up in another answer - ideally I'd have clone-stamped out the distraction lower right & cropped to expand on the cinematic feel it has, also centring the subject.
Very quick edit...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Smudge tool` and `Spot Healing Brush` both are good. Sometimes you need to use both for better results.

Basically, it depends on the complexity of the area you are working on. For ordinary ones, even `MS Paint` can do the trick.

It all depends on your skillness and practice. Try different options you will learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I don't prefer the picture WITH the building on the horizon.  But if you want it out, why not do this instead?  The right-hand part of the picture had a weak sky and distracting foreground anyway.

[image]

Comment: Personally, I kind of like the cinematic feel. I'd have clone-stamped out the distraction lower right, then cropped 1:1.85 or so & centred the subject a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, I would expect excellent results from the fill with content aware. It's also the easiest to do.

- Select area around building
- Right click (windows) and choose Fill...
- Content-Aware